# How to mock the formik useFormikContext hook when writing unit tests with jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme, formik

I have a simple component see below, that basically attempts to grab some data from the formik FormContext using the useFormikContext hook.

However when attempting to write unit tests for this component it wants me to mock the hook which is fine, however, mocking the hook with typescript means returning well over 20 properties most of which are a variety of methods and functions.

Has anyone found a better way of doing this? Just seems a bit annoying even if I get it to work as I only need 1 field from the hook.

**Component**

```
const AphControlInput: React.FC<IAphControlInput> = ({ name, value, label, type, small, disabled, vertical = true, className = '', ...attributeOptions }) => {
  const form = useFormikContext();

  return (
    <>
      <div className={
        `aph-control-input ${className}` +
        `${small ? ' aph-control-input--small' : ''}` +
        `${vertical ? ' aph-control-input--block' : ''}` +
        `${form.getFieldMeta(name).error ? ' aph-control-input--invalid' : ''}`
      }
      >
        <Field
          className='aph-control-input__input'
          name={name}
          id={value ? value?.toString() : name}
          type={type}
          value={value ? value : undefined}
          disabled={disabled}
          {...attributeOptions}
        />
        <label className='aph-control-input__text' htmlFor={value ? value?.toString() : name}>
          {label}
        </label>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Unit test** (Incomplete this was just a quick attempt at mocking all the returns for the hook)

```
describe('AphInputLabel UnitTests', () => {
  let wrapper: any;
  const useFormikContextMock = jest.spyOn(formik, 'useFormikContext');

  beforeEach(() => {
    useFormikContextMock.mockReturnValue({
      values: { testName: 'testValue' },
      getFieldMeta: getFieldMetaMock,
      touched: true,
      isSubmitting: false,
      isValidating: false,
      errors: false,
      submitCount: 0,
      setStatus: (status?: any) => { return null },
      setErrors: (errors?: FormikErrors<any>) => { return null },
      setSubmitting: (isSubmitting: boolean) => { return null },
      setTouched: (touched: FormikTouched<any>, shouldValidate?: boolean) => { return null },
      setValues: (values: React.SetStateAction<any>, shouldValidate?: boolean) => { return null },
      setFieldValue: (field: string, value: any, shouldValidate?: boolean) => { return null },
      setFieldError: (field: string, message: string | undefined) => { return null },
      setFieldTouched: (field: string, isTouched?: boolean, shouldValidate?: boolean) => { return null },
      resetForm: (nextState?: Partial<FormikState<any>>) => { return null },
      validateField: (field: string) => { return null },
      setFormikState: (f: FormikState<any> | ((prevState: FormikState<any>) => FormikState<any>), cb?: () => void) => null,
      validateForm: (values?: any) => { return new Promise<FormikErrors<unknown>>((resolve, reject) => {
        const formikErrors: FormikErrors<any> = {
          'testName': ''
        }
          return formikErrors;
        });
      },
      submitForm: () => new Promise<void>(() => null),
      handleSubmit: (e?: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> | undefined) => null,
      handleReset: (e?: React.SyntheticEvent<any>) => null,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you import ```formik``` on this line : ```const useFormikContextMock = jest.spyOn(formik, 'useFormikContext');```

Comment: Where is ```getFieldMetaMock``` as well please?

Comment: I have updated the answer to hopefully provide more detail let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved this issue not 100% sure it is the best solution but have posted here in case it helps anyone with a similar issue.

I basically overwrote the FormikType allowing me to ignore all of the fields and methods I wasn't using, it clearly has some drawbacks as it is removing the type-safety, but I figured since it was only inside the unit test it is somewhat okay.

**Import**

```
import * as Formik from 'formik';
```

**Test setup**

```
describe('AphControlInput: UnitTests', () => {
  let wrapper: any;
  const useFormikContextMock = jest.spyOn(Formik, 'useFormikContext');

  beforeEach(() => {
    useFormikContextMock.mockReturnValue({
      getFieldMeta: getFieldMetaMock
    } as unknown as any);

    wrapper = shallow(
      <AphTextInput {...baseComponentProps} />
    );
  });
}
```

**Helper method**

```
export const getFieldMetaMock = (name: string) => {
  return ({
    value: 'testValue',
    initialTouched: true,
    touched: false,
  });
};
```

Comment: Would mind to share more details ,  I need help on this issue, I added questions on your post

Comment: Thanks , please also add this ```useFormikContextMock``` declaration

Comment: Because here formik has a small letter f :
```const useFormikContextMock = jest.spyOn(formik, 'useFormikContext');```

How is it imported ?

Comment: I have updated to include the const declarations

Comment: Thanks so much, let me test again

Comment: It worked, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can mock the Formik library & its desired functions, in this way:

```
jest.mock('formik', () => ({
  useFormikContext: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    getFieldMeta: jest.fn(),
  }),
}));
```

Just put this code at the top of your unit test file, outside of the `describe` scope.

Comment: Great answer but it won't work if you are destructuring `useFormikContext` in your code. In this case, omit the `jest.fn().mockReturnValue` and just return the object directly